# Андроид клавиатура preview не для всех клавиш

Tags: java, android

Столкнулся с таким вопросом. Делаю клавиатуру под андроид, при нажатии на клавишу над ней всплывает превью с нажатым символом. Как сделать так, что бы превью не всплывало над клавишей пробел shift и т.д.

Есть вот такой код:

Само превью:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@color/key_preview_background"
    android:textColor="@color/key_preview_text_color"
    android:textSize="25sp" />
```

клавиатура:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/keyboard"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:keyPreviewHeight="35dp"
    android:keyPreviewLayout="@layout/preview" />
```

Разметка клавиш:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:horizontalGap="5px"
    android:verticalGap="5px"
    android:keyHeight="50dp">

    <Row>
        <Key android:codes="49" android:keyLabel="1" />
        <Key android:codes="50" android:keyLabel="2" />
        <Key android:codes="51" android:keyLabel="3" />
        <Key android:codes="52" android:keyLabel="4" />
        <Key android:codes="53" android:keyLabel="5" />
        <Key android:codes="54" android:keyLabel="6" />
        <Key android:codes="55" android:keyLabel="7" />
        <Key android:codes="56" android:keyLabel="8" />
        <Key android:codes="57" android:keyLabel="9" />
        <Key android:codes="48" android:keyLabel="0" />
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Key android:codes="64" android:keyLabel="\@" />
        <Key android:codes="35" android:keyLabel="#" />
        <Key android:codes="36" android:keyLabel="$" />
        <Key android:codes="37" android:keyLabel="%" />
        <Key android:codes="38" android:keyLabel="&amp;" />
        <Key android:codes="42" android:keyLabel="*" />
        <Key android:codes="45" android:keyLabel="-" />
        <Key android:codes="43" android:keyLabel="+" />
        <Key android:codes="40" android:keyLabel="(" />
        <Key android:codes="41" android:keyLabel=")" />
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Key android:codes="-1" android:keyIcon="@drawable/ic_keyboard_capslock_white_24dp" />
        <Key android:codes="33" android:keyLabel="!" />
        <Key android:codes="34" android:keyLabel="&#34;" />
        <Key android:codes="39" android:keyLabel="'" />
        <Key android:codes="58" android:keyLabel=":" />
        <Key android:codes="59" android:keyLabel=";" />
        <Key android:codes="47" android:keyLabel="/" />
        <Key android:codes="63" android:keyLabel="\?" />
        <Key android:codes="-5" android:keyIcon="@drawable/ic_backspace_white_24dp"
            android:isRepeatable="true" android:keyEdgeFlags="right" android:keyWidth="15%p" />
    </Row>
    <Row android:rowEdgeFlags="bottom">
        <Key android:codes="-6" android:keyLabel="ABC"  android:keyWidth="20%p" android:keyEdgeFlags="left" />
        <Key android:codes="44" android:keyLabel=","/>
        <Key android:codes="32" android:keyLabel=" " android:keyWidth="40%p" android:isRepeatable="true"/>
        <Key android:codes="46" android:keyLabel="." />
        <Key android:codes="-4" android:keyIcon="@drawable/ic_keyboard_return_white_24dp"
            android:keyWidth="20%p" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>
    </Row>

</Keyboard>
```